# Julia DifferentialEquations.jl says "InexactError"

Tags: julia, differential-equations

This is my first attempt on a complex coupled ode equation:

```
using DifferentialEquations
using Plots

function chaos!(dx, x, p, t)
    dx[1] = 1im*((p[3] * x[1] - 2 * real(x[2])) * x[1] - 0.5) -  x[1] / 2 
    dx[2] = -1im*(0.5 * p[2] * abs(x[2])^2 + x[2]) - x[2] * p[1] / 2
end

x0 = [1, 1];
tspan = (0, 100);
p =[0.001, 1.4, -0.95]
prob = ODEProblem(chaos!, x0, tspan, p)

sol = solve(prob,Tsit5())
```

And it goes:

```
ERROR: InexactError: Float64(-0.5 - 3.45im)
Stacktrace:
  [1] Real
    @ .\complex.jl:44 [inlined]
  [2] convert
    @ .\number.jl:7 [inlined]
  [3] setindex!
    @ .\array.jl:903 [inlined]
  [4] chaos!(dx::Vector{Float64}, x::Vector{Float64}, p::Vector{Float64}, t::Float64)
    @ Main .\Untitled-1:5
  [5] ODEFunction
    @ C:\Users\CTCY\.julia\packages\SciMLBase\BoNUy\src\scimlfunctions.jl:345 [inlined]
.....
```

I don't quite get what it is trying to tell me. What does "inexacterror" even means?

Comment: The compiler does not see complex numbers in the setup of the solver, so derives all types as based on Float64. Then the solver is surprised by having to fit a complex number into the space of a single float. I think that having to throw away a substantial imaginary part leads to the "inexacterror". Perhaps you can force the desired behavior by initializing `x0` with `1+0*1im`.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you! I have solved my problem with you suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial condition needs to be complex:

```
x0 = ComplexF64[1, 1];
```